# What does generic refer to in probability?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, terminology, stochastic-processes

I see from many probability theory or stochastic theory books,  they mention generic probability, generic distribution, etc.  So what is the formal definition of "generic" in probability and statistics, could anyone show some official definition or related explanations in mathematics books and examples?

Comment: It might depend on context. Can you offer an explicit example, in context, with a proper reference?

Comment: @Glen_b♦ e.g. in the poisson process, each interval arrival times Xi is generic variable

Comment: I mean *please quote a source so we can see the* ***context*** -- *i.e the surrounding text -- in which they use the term generic*.

Comment: @Glen_b♦ I don't have a source at hand. The e.g. I mentioned is the words of instructor from a lecture I attended. He mentioned that when reading the poisson definition.

Comment: Sounds like it could be similar to be "[general position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position)" in computational geometry, which essentially means "excluding certain degenerate cases (for simplicity)"?